# schemaSpy for sqlserver2008?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, schemaspy

iam using sqlserver2008, Does this work for sqlserver2008??

i have given
java -jar "D:\Program Files\SchemaSpy\schemaSpyGUI.jar" -dp "D:\jtds-1.2.5-dist\jtds-1.2.5.jar" -t mssql-jtds -db EnterpriseVaultDirectory -host localhost -port 1433 -u sa -connprops "D:\Program Files\SchemaSpy\properties\mssql-jtds.properties" -o "D:\Schema"

STill its not working...

Can anyone please Help Me

Comment: No one to help me...??? Iam auctully getting schemaSpy generated but it has only Empty Folder got generated But nothing in it

Answer (score 2):

1. please check "D:\Program Files\SchemaSpy\schemaSpyGUI.jar"? 
   schemaSpyGUI.jar is just UI program. 
   you need schemaspy 5.0.0 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/schemaspy/files/latest/download?source=files)
   and use like this (java -jar "your_path\schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar" ...)
2. If it is possible, use latest version of the jtds (currently jtds-1.3.0.jar).
3. replace "-t mssql-jtds" with your file that you modified 'mssql-jtds.properties' for your system(I use mssql05-jtds_mysystem that I eidted with mssql05-jtd.properties(see the below). so I do not use connprops option.
   of course -t option no need extentname part(=>.properties).
4. Why don't you use Graphviz. that makes simple ERD images. you have to add -gv option

   ----the below----

   ```
   # see http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/dbtypes.html
   # for configuration / customization details
   #

   # Provided by Ernest Zapata, Larry Walker and Emilian Turbatu
   description=jTDS JDBC Driver for Microsoft SQL 2000/2005 Server 

   # majority of settings are identical to jTDS: 
   extends=mssql-jtds

   # return the table comments
   selectTableCommentsSql=SELECT OBJECT_NAME(t.object_id) AS TABLE_NAME, ex.value AS comments FROM ( sys.tables t LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties ex ON ex.major_id = t.object_id AND ex.name = 'MS_Description' AND minor_id = 0) \ **--> You must change this line! you need () and no line feed'\'** 
   JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id AND s.name = :schema \
   WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(t.object_id, 'IsMsShipped')=0 \
   ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(t.object_id)

   # return the column comments
   selectColumnCommentsSql=SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) AS TABLE_NAME, c.name AS COLUMN_NAME, ex.value AS comments \
   FROM sys.columns c \
   LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties ex \
   ON ex.major_id = c.object_id AND ex.minor_id = c.column_id AND ex.name = 'MS_Description' \
   JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id \
   JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id AND s.name = :schema \
   WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(c.object_id, 'IsMsShipped')=0 \
   ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id), c.column_id
   ```

Comment: This was a great tip, java.exe -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -t customDBProps -host localhost -port 1433 -db MyDB -u sa -p Password -s MySchema -o "C:\users\me\desktop\schema" -gv "release" -dp "driverJTDS\jtds-1.3.1.jar"
I put the the GV in a folder called release and the JTDS driver in a folder called driverJTDS. Worked perfectly - SQL2008

Answer (score 1):

worked for me doing this:
getting java
setting jar with jarfix
download schemaSpyGui 
download schemaSpy
download mssql-tds driver
unzip schemaSpyGui
unzip schemaSpy in the schemaSpyGui folder
unzip mssql-tds driver in the schemaSpyGui/drivers/mssql-tds folder

PARAMS 
dbtype: mssql-tds
set host, set port, set user, set password
set path driver
set path schema spy
set output path, charset 

however there is  bug with mssql 2008 r2